# Simon game made with ECMAScript HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

How does my HTML and CSS look? I'm a beginner so I have no idea if this is good design or not.

Is there an easier way to copy and paste code here? Everytime I paste my code in here and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, only a few lines at the top of my code are formatted, and for the rest I have to go down with a spacebar constantly which is really annoying.

[Here](https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/JLBpNQ?editors=1010) is a link to the full game with all the HTML and CSS.

```
const simonHTML = {
 power : document.querySelector('.powerButton'),
 strictButton : document.getElementById('strict'),
 startButton : document.getElementById('start'),
 displayScore : document.getElementById('score'),
 colors : document.getElementsByClassName('color')
}

const game = {
 on : false,
 start : false,
 strict : false,
 playerTurn : false,
 turn : 1,
 score : 0,
 counter : 0,
 computerMoves : [],
 playerMoves : [],
 colors : [greenBox = document.getElementById('green'), 
 blueBox = document.getElementById('blue'), 
 yellowBox = document.getElementById('yellow'), 
 redBox = document.getElementById('red')]
}

//move the purple div back and forth
function turnOn () {
  if(!game.on){
    simonHTML.power.classList.add('moveRight');
    simonHTML.power.classList.remove('moveLeft')
    game.on = true;
    simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = game.score.toString();
}  
else if(game.on){ 
    simonHTML.power.classList.remove('moveRight');
    simonHTML.power.classList.add('moveLeft'); 
    game.on = false; 
    game.turn = 1;
    game.score = 0;
    game.counter = 0;
    resetMoves();
    simonHTML.strictButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    simonHTML.startButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    game.start = false;
    game.strict = false;
    simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = '-';
  } 
 }

function randomMoves (num) {
 for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
  let moves = game.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.colors.length)]
  game.computerMoves.push(moves);
  console.log(game.computerMoves);
}
return game.computerMoves;
}

function resetMoves () {
 game.computerMoves = [];
 game.playerMoves = [];
}

 const colors = [
    new Map([[green, "lime"], [yellow, "#FF6"], [blue, "dodgerblue"], [red, "salmon"]]),
    new Map([[green, "green"], [yellow, "#CC0"], [red, "red"], [blue, "blue"]])
];

const sounds = {
 green : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"),
  blue : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"),
  yellow : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"),
  red : new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3")
 };


  function showMoves() {
    let i = 0;
    game.playerTurn = false;
    const start = setInterval(function() {
      if(!game.on){
    clearInterval(start);
  }
    if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
      clearInterval(start);
      game.playerTurn = true;
      return;
  }

  const move = game.computerMoves[i];
  setLight(move, true);
  setTimeout(setLight.bind(null, move, false), 1000); //Using bind to preset arguments

  i++;
 }, 2000);
}

function setLight(color, isOn) {
  if(isOn){
   sounds[color.id].play();
   }
   color.style.backgroundColor = isOn ? colors[0].get(color) : colors[1].get(color);
  }

  function compareMoves(e){
    if(e === game.computerMoves[game.counter]){
      game.counter++;
       if(game.playerMoves.length === game.computerMoves.length && e === game.computerMoves[game.computerMoves.length-1]){
          simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = ++game.score;
          resetMoves();
          randomMoves(++game.turn);
          showMoves();
          game.counter = 0;
        }
  } else if(game.strict) {
    game.counter = 0;
    game.turn = 0;
    game.score = 0;
    simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = game.score;
    resetMoves();
    randomMoves(++game.turn);
    showMoves();

 } else {
  game.playerMoves = [];
  game.counter = 0;
  showMoves();
 }
}

function playerMoveDown(e){
  if(game.playerTurn){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[0].get(e.target);
    let color = e.target.id;
    let compare = e.target;
    sounds[color].play();
    game.playerMoves.push(e.target);
    compareMoves(compare);
    console.log(game.playerMoves + 'down');
    }
   }

 function playerMoveUp(e){
   e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[1].get(e.target);
  }

 for (let i = 0; i < simonHTML.colors.length; i++){
  simonHTML.colors[i].addEventListener('mousedown', playerMoveDown);
  simonHTML.colors[i].addEventListener('mouseup', playerMoveUp);
 }

 //for purple button
 simonHTML.power.addEventListener('click', turnOn);  

 simonHTML.strictButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(game.on){
     if(!game.strict){
      simonHTML.strictButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
       game.strict = true;
    } else if(game.strict){
       simonHTML.strictButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       game.strict = false;
    }
   }
  });

 simonHTML.startButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(game.on){
     if(!game.start){
       game.start = true;
       simonHTML.startButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
       randomMoves(game.turn);
       showMoves();
     } else if (game.start){
       game.start = false;
       simonHTML.startButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       resetMoves();
       game.turn = 1;
       game.score = 0;
       simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = game.score;
    }
   } 
  });
```

html -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Simon Game</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='./main.css'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='./simon.js' async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container outer centered'>
            <div id = 'blue' class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'red'  class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'controller' class='centered'>
                <h3>Simon</h3>
              <div class='options flex-row'>
                <div class='center-options'>
                    <h4>Score</h4>
                    <h5 id='score'>-</h5>
                </div>
                <div class='center-options'>
                  <h4>Start</h4>
                  <div id='start' class='on-circle'></div>
                </div>
                <div class='center-options'>
                  <h4>Strict</h4>
                  <div id='strict' class='on-circle'></div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div id='onOff' class='flex-row'>
               <h4>Off</h4>
               <div>
                 <div class='powerButton'></div>
               </div>
               <h4>On</h4>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div id = 'green'  class= 'color shade'></div>
            <div id = 'yellow'  class= 'color shade'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css -

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-row{
    width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

 .center-options{
    align-self:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
}

body{
    background-color: gray;
}

.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.outer{
    height: 30em;
    width:30em;
    background-color:rgba(21, 56, 41, 1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
}

/*=============Color buttons=================*/

.color{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#green{
    background-color:green;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-right:5px solid
}

#blue{
    background-color:blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-right:5px solid
}

#yellow{
    background-color:rgb(204,204,0);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-left:5px solid;
}

#red{
    background-color:red;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    border-left: 5px solid;
}

/*=============Controller=================*/

#controller{
    z-index: 1;
    height:14em;
    width:14em;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    border: 10px solid;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}

#controller h3{
    margin-top:1em;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.options{
  margin-top: .5em;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}

.on-circle{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*===============off-on================*/

#onOff{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}

#onOff h4:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:20px;
}

#onOff h4:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

#onOff > div {
  height:2em;
  border-radius:10%;
  width:4em;
  background-color:#404040;
}

#onOff > div > div {
  height:100%;
  width:35%;
  background-color:purple;
  margin-left:1px;
  border-radius:10%;
  border:3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.moveRight{
    transition: all .2s linear;
    transform: translateX(2.5em);
}

.moveLeft{
    transition: all .2s linear; 
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: If you also want a review of the generated HTML and the CSS, please add them as code blocks to your question.  Regarding your code formatting question: It should be sufficient to mark every line of the code and press Ctrl+k. This adds four spaces in front of every line.